# Need a better way to compare multiple values against a property and return true;

Tags: c#, string, compare

I am looking for a standard / best practice for scenarios where I need to check the same property of an object against a list of values returning true if any of the values match the property.

Currently the code resembles this (I didn't write it, I am looking to refactor it)...

```
if (object.property == "string1"
                    || object.property == "string2"
                    || object.property == "string3"
                        || object.property == "string4"
                        || object.property == "string5"
                                || object.property == "string6"
                                || object.property == "string7"
                                    || object.property == "string8"
                                     || object.property == "string9"
                                        || object.property == "string10"
                                        || object.property == "string11"
                                            || object.property == "string12"
                                            || object.property == "string13"
                                                || object.property == "string14"
                                                || object.property == "string15")
```

Comment: if you've const strings - than use `switch-case` construction.

Comment: All valid answers and much nicer than what I provided.  Good job guys.  I am going to give Andrew my vote because it appears to be the most readable and should allocate the least amount of memory as it is using a string array.  Again Many thanks for the great answers.

Answer (score 9):

```
IEnumerable<string> items = new List<string>{ "string1", "string2" };

bool match = items.Contains(object.property);
```

Comment: HashSet<String> would be a better solution. O(1) instead of O(n).
... assuming that you reuse the HashSet<String>, and not build it every time.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers suggest using a `List<string>`, but `HashSet<string>` is better suited for this task:

```
HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>() { "string1", "string2", ..., "string15" }; 

if (set.Contains(object.Property))
    //... do something ...
```

Or, as anatoliiG suggests, let the compiler handle it:

```
switch (object.property)
{
    case "string1":
    case "string2":
    //...
    case "string15":
       //... do something ...
       break;
}
```

Comment: Just make sure you reuse the HashSet, or there will be no performance benefit over List<T>.

Comment: If the hashset is already computed, it might be faster than a giant switch statement (especially true for larger datasets).

Comment: @Mark absolutely right, and thanks for pointing that out.  The `new Foo()` construction in example code often leads to inefficient or incorrect code; `new Random()` is a frequent example of that.

Comment: @Matthew I don't know much about how the compiler handles switch statements with strings, but with integer switches it uses a jump table where it can.  There might be some optimization for string switches as well.  I don't have time to compile and disassemble an example myself, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the values in a `List<string>` and then do this:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>() {"string1", "string2"};

if(values.Contains(object.Property)) return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try LINQ for a more concise code, such as:

```
bool match = new string[] { "string1", "string2" }.Any(p => p == object.property);
```

Comment: Downvoting for many reasons. Not the least of which is the use of "Count() > 0" instead of Any();

Comment: You have quotes around object.property. That is clearly not what you meant.
Also, for more concise, how about new[] {"string1", "string2"}. You don't need the "String" in there, it can be inferred.
Done.

Comment: Very good about the fact string can be inferred.  I never thought of that.  Yes, I didn't mean quotes around obj.prop.